# T4 and first countable topology that is non metrizable

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, first-countable

Does anyone know any example of such topology?

Comment: Does T4 imply Hausdorff for you?

Comment: @Miha: $T_n$ for $n>2$ *should* always imply Hausdorff. "Normal" need not imply Hausdorff, though, unless the definition of "normal" assumes that finite sets are closed.

Comment: Yes, T4=> Hausdorff and regularity

Comment: @Cameron: It *should*, but unfortunately the opposite convention is also found, so it’s usually a good idea to ask.

Comment: @Brian: That *is* unfortunate. I'll have to bear that in mind.

Answer (score 11):

The [Sorgenfrey Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line) is $T_4$ and first-countable. It cannot be metrizable since it has a countable dense subset $\Bbb Q$ but has no countable base, that means it is separable without being second-countable.

Comment: Alternatively, it cannot be metrizable because its square isn’t normal.

Comment: Ok, the sorgenfrey line, always a good counter-example. It is perfectly normal too.

Answer (score 8):

The first uncountable ordinal with the order topology is normal, first countable and even locally metrizable - but it is not metrizable, since it is non-compact despite the fact that it is sequentially compact